# SetState in ReactJs, fiddle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Been struggling the last couple of days with a reactJs-app.

I have created the following fiddle to demonstatrate.

Im my 'real' app the state is not hard-coded in the constructor but fetched from a DB in `componentDidMount()`

Here is the fiddle which contains some more info.
http://jsfiddle.net/bzc9j8ku/4/

Please have look! 
Thanks

Comment: OK but what is the problem?

Comment: First problem is that when you click on a name to choose a driver an 'lag' occurs. Meaning that the cars that gets alerted actually belongs to the driver you clicked Before the 'new' driver.
Second problems is displaying the cars after the getCars() is finished.
Thank you!

Comment: Well that's because you choose the cars based on the setState, but the value isnt 'set' yet. Why not pass the selected driver to the getCars method, and set the state with both data (so it wont render twice)

Comment: Ok, So i should not setState of choosenDriver in the handleEventClick but instead set both the driver and cars in getCars(). I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

var carsForDriver = this.getCars(selectedDriver); // Change method to support it and not get it from state

this.setState({
choosenDriver: selectedDriver,
carsOfChoosenDriver: carsForDriver}

Comment: Thank you very much, Im gonna try this.

Comment: The problem I found wiyh this approach is that I can not use getCars() without first have a selectedDriver choosen. I assume that you suggest me to setState after getCars() finishes.

Comment: Thank you! I got It working  after playing around with this suggestion.